# RedHat is not resolving local windows dns entries

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, redhat

On the RedHat box, I can ping a DNS entry only if I include the full name.  For example: `ping box.example.com` works but `ping box` does not.  Strange thing is, I can `ping box` from a resent version of Ubuntu and from any Windows box.

On any computer, the command `dig box.example.com` does show the resolved IP address in the ANSWERS SECTION.  Using just the box name `dig box` does not show the resolved IP address.

My `resolv.conf` is fine.

Red Hat Linux release 9 (Shrike)

The response to `dig box` contains this line:

```
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 38217
```

Please remember though, this somehow magically works the other servers.  Are Ubuntu and Windows somehow enhancing the DNS lookup?  Please suggest where I might go from here.

Comment: Adding `domain example.com` to `/etc/resolv.conf` allows me to `ping box`... Is this the best way to fix this?

Comment: Do a man resolv.conf. I think you have answered your own question. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an entry `domain example.com` in your `/etc/resolv.conf`

Additionally, it *may* be necessary to modify the entries in the `hosts` line `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, otherwise it may happen that `dig`works but applications (i.e. `ping`, `telnet`, `wget` etc.) don't (or was it the other way round?).

Comment: I checked more closely: My additional remark about nsswitch applies only if your local domain is `domain.local`. (Only) in that case you should have `hosts: files dns mdns4` there.